# Codecademy - a night at movies 4/10: Prompting: Redux

Tags: ruby

I can't find the error, it keeps telling me: Oops, try again. It looks like you didn't add to the movies hash!
Thank you.

```
   movies = { 'himym' => 5, 
   'oitnb' => 4 }
  puts "Which one do you like better?"
  choice = gets.chomp

 case choice
 when "add"
 puts "What is your favorite movie?"
 title = gets.chomp
 puts "What would you rate it?"
 rating = gets.chomp
 movies = {}
 movies[title] = rating
 puts "#{title} with rating #{rating} has been added!"
 when "update"
 puts "Updated!"
 when "display"
 puts "Movies!"
 when "delete"
 puts "Deleted!"
 else
 puts "Error!"
 end
```

Comment: I suggest that you correct your indentation in the post. Second, Try running the program locally on your machine. With Ruby installed, in the terminal run `ruby ./night_at_the_movies.rb`. You will then get an error at the first incorrect line.

Comment: https://www.codecademy.com/en/forum_questions/538652267c82cadb40000811

Answer (score 1):

I tested your code - I got stuck in the same part. Instructions at CodeAcademy are not always clear. Your code, according to what CA is asking is right, you just need to write "add" as an answer for "Which one do you like better?" when testing code at CA's virtual machine. So:

```
choice = "add"
```

That way you will be running your case/when filter. Got it?